Draw a density function that depends on the inverse normal law
I'm trying to draw the density function from Vasicek's ASRF model. The problem is that I can't find a way to use the inverse normal law other than by using an approximation (see below). I can't keep this, I would like to have a way to calculate the inverse normal distribution more quickly and simply:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

% Approximation pour erf
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{erf}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{%
        (1 - exp(-#1^2 * (4/pi + 0.147 * #1^2) / (1 + 0.147 * #1^2)))%
    }%
}

% Approximation pour erfinv (Winitzki's approximation)
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{erfinv}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{%
        sign(#1) * sqrt(%
            sqrt((2/(pi * 0.147) + ln(1-#1^2)/2)^2 - ln(1-#1^2)/0.147) - %
            (2/(pi * 0.147) + ln(1-#1^2)/2)%
        )%
    }%
}

% Normale cumulative (CDF)
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{normcdf}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{0.5 * (1 + erf(#1 / sqrt(2)))}%
}

% Normale inverse (Quantile)
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{norminv}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{sqrt(2) * erfinv(2 * #1 - 1)}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Graphique du modèle ASRF}

\section{Formule du modèle}
La fonction est donnée par : 
\[
K = \sqrt{\frac{R}{1-R}} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2R} \left( \sqrt{1-R}~G(\mathrm{PD}) - G(0.02) \right)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \left( G(\mathrm{PD}) \right)^2 \right),
\]
où :
\begin{itemize}
    \item \( N \) est la fonction de répartition de la loi normale centrée réduite.
    \item \( G \) est la réciproque de cette fonction (\( G(x) = N^{-1}(x) \)).
    \item \( R \) est le coefficient de corrélation des actifs.
    \item \( \mathrm{PD} \) est la probabilité de défaut.
\end{itemize}

\section{Graphique}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=14cm, height=8cm,
        xlabel={\(\mathrm{PD}\) (Probabilité de défaut)},
        ylabel={\(K\) (Exigence de capital)},
        xmin=0, xmax=0.12,
        ymin=0, ymax=50,
        grid=both,
        major grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!50},
        minor grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!20},
        legend pos=north west,
        legend style={draw=none, fill=none, font=\small}
    ]
    
    % Tracé de la fonction pour R = 0.1
    \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=2000, thick, blue] 
    {sqrt((1-0.1)/(0.1))*exp(-1/(2*0.1)*(sqrt(1-0.1)*norminv(x)-norminv(0.02))^2+0.5 * (norminv(x))^2)};
    \addlegendentry{\(R = 0.1\)}
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}



My MWE has a sample of 2000 in the tikzpicture because of the image below. Be patient if you compile.
Thank you.


Do you want to smoothen the curve? Try \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=2000, thick, blue, smooth]. Also, I suggest that you compile the curve separately and then place the PDF in your document via \includegraphics. There is also the option to use gnuplot which might be faster.

Thanks, you solve half of my problem. As for plotting, I have already done it under GNU plot but I want to do it under LaTeX for several reasons:
1: the color of the curve will be determined by the main color of the document. If I change the color of the document I don't want to retrace the curve in GNU plot.
2. I will probably have to modify the size of the graphs and change the value of the parameters (R=0.1, 0.2 etc.) and it will be too complicated if I have to externalize the graph each time.

Try this path: 1) use R (or similar programs) to calculate what you need; e.g. you could increase density of points around the maximum, 2) use R to save those data as a table or in pgfplots coordinates format, 3) plot said data with pgfplots. In other words: separate calculation from display.

You can also view the calculation as running a parameter scan. Ee.g. now the domain depends on x, which you could read as x(t) = p(t) = 1 * t. You could replace this linear function by a non-linear p, which: a) has high densities around the maximum, b) lower denisties elsewhere. p(t) could be discrete (e.g. high density of points around maximum), or continuous.
